# Sending paramter to php rest api call

Tags: php, rest

I'm making REST API in PHP. One of the functions is to get record from database by passing record ID.

**DbOperation.php**

```
function getOrdersByID($orderID){
    
        $sql = "SELECT DO_No, DO_Date, LI_Article, LI_Lib FROM magoopf where DO_No = ?";
                
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $orderID);
        
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($do_no, $do_date, $li_article, $li_lib);
         
        $outputdata = array(); 
         
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $hero  = array();
            $hero['do_no'] = $do_no; 
            $hero['do_date'] = $do_date; 
            $hero['li_article'] = $li_article; 
            $hero['li_lib'] = $li_lib; 
            
             
            array_push($outputdata, $hero); 
        }
        return $outputdata; 
    }
```

**Api.php**

```
 $response = array();
 
 if(isset($_GET['apicall']))
 { 
     switch($_GET['apicall'])
     {   
         //the READ operation
         //if the call is getheroes
         case 'getorders':
         $db = new DbOperation();
         $response['error'] = false; 
         $response['message'] = 'Successfully completed';
         $response['outputdata'] = $db->getOrders();
         break; 
         
         case 'getordersbyid':       
         $db = new DbOperation();
         $result = $db->getOrdersByID($_GET['orderid']);         
         {
             $response['error'] = false; 
             $response['message'] = 'Successfully';
             $response['outputdata'] = $db->getOrdersByID($_GET['orderid']);
         }
         break; 
     
 
 }
 }
 else{
     //if it is not api call 
     //pushing appropriate values to response array 
     $response['error'] = true; 
     $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
 }
 
 echo json_encode($response);
```

When I call api by `http://localhost:8090/api.php?apicall=getordersbyid$orderid=21/00010`

as result I get `[]`

But record with with `id = '21/00010'` exist in database. I guess passing id to api is wrong... i don't have a clue where is mistake?

Comment: `$orderid=21/00010` is a typo here or real?

Comment: Typo: `$orderid=` should be `&orderid=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect GET parameters. Instead of $ you should use &.
Try this URL: `http://localhost:8090/api.php?apicall=getordersbyid&orderid=21/00010`

Comment: Don't post an answer when it's just a simple typo. Questions like this should be closed and deleted, and an answer slows that down.